# How to persist a Realm inMemory database to local storage?

Tags: android, realm

My current Android Application employs Realm as the local database.

The database is populated by downloading data via a REST API.

The total amount of data is approx 800MB.

Currently this is taking around three hours to retrieve and persist to disk.

Each REST API call takes approx 4 seconds

I am regularly compacting my realm using

```
Realm.compactRealm(realmConfiguration);
```

which takes approx 50 seconds each time.

I am now attempting to improve this situation and have tried configuring my realm to be inMemory().

This means I do not have to compact at all and from my initial timings I believe I can store my data in under 30 minutes.

However I need a mechanism that allows me to "replicate" the `inMemory()` realm onto my internal storage in "Bulk".

I've looked at the Realm API and there doesn't appear to be anything obvious to create one realm based on another, especially when the source realm is in memory.

What options do I have? (If any)

Comment: [`realm.writeCopyTo(File)`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#writeCopyTo-java.io.File-)?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this indeed looks as if it allows me to persist my inMemory() database to a file. Can I then open a persistent Realm using ths compacted file? the docs are vague on this only mentioning reading from the Asset folder to initialise a Realm.

Comment: Of course, if you don't specify it as `inMemory()` and you specify the file parameter (which I think is technically `directory()` + `name()`, where `name` should contain `___.realm`)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this approach works, however... I have to stop my app running then start it again before I see the data in the persisted Realm copied from  the inMemory() realm. Hwo do you get Realm to re read the underlying dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not seeing the persisted Realm. But `realm.refresh()` forces a re-read. However if you are overwriting the file, you might need to have the Realm instance closed before overwriting the file.

Comment: I wasnt closing all the instances before trying to delete the file. Its working brilliantly now. Thanks very much for your help @EpicPandaForce